# how to pass Empty string string into a xml file using Datastage?

Tags: xml, database, datastage

**This is the XSD which is being used in the job to create xml output file fetching records from tables:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
    <xsd:element name="MANIFEST">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Header">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="SubmissionDate" type="xsd:date"/>
                            <xsd:element name="SubmissionTime" type="xsd:time"/>
                            <xsd:element name="RequestingApplication" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="ContentType" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="Documents">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="Document" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="SearchMetadata" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:sequence>
                                                    <xsd:element name="Attribute" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                                <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                                <xsd:element name="Value" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                </xsd:sequence>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="UpdateMetadata" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:sequence>
                                                    <xsd:element name="Attribute" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                                <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                                <xsd:element name="Value" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                </xsd:sequence>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="Trailer">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="DocumentCount" type="xsd:int"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="BatchID" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Now when we are not getting any records from table the documents part in the output file is only showing like :  
It is not showing other child elements like , .
Is it possible to create file having documents part like below:

```
<Documents/>
   <Document/>
      <SearchMetadata/>
........
.....
..
```